# Invalid login credentails - Magento Connect Manager / downloader

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, module, magento-connect, downloader

I have some problem! Invalid login credentails. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsIIQ.png

History: 
I transferred a complete archive folder magento of my site (htdocs - magento.tar). Moved from one stack to another identical same.

Bitnami stack Magento 1.8.0.0-1. Installed correctly. Everything is stable. Except for one thing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsIIQ.png

I can not log in MagentoConnect downloader in the back-and on my site. Invalid login credentails. 
Maybe the problem connect.cfg or local.xml?

Please help, 
Need any decisions and advice.

Thanks

Comment: How i control other phone by my phone without telling him

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141335)

Answer (score 6):

What you can try here is to delete the file `downloader/connect.cfg`. This file should be created the next time you load the Magento Connect section of the website.

I would always suggest taking a backup of files before deleting them though just for the case that something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Open phpmyadmin and go to your database's admin_user table. you can modify you admin credentials here.Click Edit against given data and modify username/password (be sure to select function MD5 for password) and click Go. You should be able to login using your new login credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your `ftp/folder` details in `downloader/connect.cfg`

This file holds your old credential, that's why it cannot login.

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....